# Python library for data scaling, centering and Box-Cox transformation

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Is there any package in Python that does data transformation: scaling, centering and Box-Cox transformation to eliminate skewness of data?
In R this could be done using `caret` package:

```
set.seed(1)
predictors = data.frame(x1 = rnorm(1000,
                                   mean = 5,
                                   sd = 2),
                        x2 = rexp(1000,
                                  rate=10))

require(caret)

trans = preProcess(predictors, 
                   c("BoxCox", "center", "scale"))
predictorsTrans = data.frame(
      trans = predict(trans, predictors))
```

I know about `sklearn`, but I was unable to find the above-mentioned processing functions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For scaling and centering you can use `preprocessing` from `sklearn`:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
centered_scaled_data = preprocessing.scale(original_data)
```

For Box-Cox you can use `boxcox` from `scipy`:

```
from scipy.stats import boxcox
boxcox_transformed_data = boxcox(original_data)
```

For calculation of skewness you can use `skew` from `scipy`:

```
from scipy.stats import skew
skness = skew(original_data)
```

You can read more details about [Resolving Skewness in this post](http://shahramabyari.com/2015/12/21/data-preparation-for-predictive-modeling-resolving-skewness/). Also, you can find more details about [Centering & Scaling here](http://shahramabyari.com/2015/12/20/data-preparation-for-predictive-modeling-centering-scaling/).

Comment: scikit-learn is in progress of adding support for Box-Cox transforms as well: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6675

Comment: Both links are broken.

Comment: By using sklearn.preprocessing, you can scale or transform your data. 
Note: in sklearn version 0.23, the default method for power transformer is 'Yeo-Johnson' instead of Box-cox in prior versions [Box-cox only works for non-negative data]
A good comparison of when to use which scalar & transformation is summarized on https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_all_scaling.html#normalizer

Answer (score 2):

Now **scikit-learn** has a method to do what you want. This provides a familiar API and is easy to put into pipelines.

sklearn version 0.20.0 has a **Box-Cox** transformation available through the `power_transform` method. This method applies Box-Cox and then applies zero-mean, unit-variance normalization to the data. You can edit the default normalization with (`standardize=False`).

```
sklearn.preprocessing.power_transform(X, method=’box-cox’, standardize=True, copy=True)
```

> Apply a power transform featurewise to make data more Gaussian-like.
>
> Power transforms are a family of parametric, monotonic transformations
>   that are applied to make data more Gaussian-like. This is useful for
>   modeling issues related to heteroscedasticity (non-constant variance),
>   or other situations where normality is desired.
>
> Currently, power_transform() supports the Box-Cox transform. Box-Cox
>   requires input data to be strictly positive. The optimal parameter for
>   stabilizing variance and minimizing skewness is estimated through
>   maximum likelihood.
>
> By default, zero-mean, unit-variance normalization is applied to the
>   transformed data.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.power_transform.html

The primary docs page doesn't mention it, but `power_transform` also supports **Yeo-Johnson** transformation.

The docs also have a nice explanation here:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing-transformer

Comment: This is a good library you are referring to, but I almost missed it. Consider editing your answere by adding a few lines of code.

Comment: This is indeed a good answer. Using `scikit-learn`'s alternative can also be a good way to validate your transformations obtained through `Scipy`.